# Can't run thunar-volman

Tags: thunar

Whenever I try to run `thunar-volman` (from a terminal), I get there following error:

`thunar-volman: Must specify the new HAL device UDI with --device-added.`

How can I get thunar-volman to work? Or is there another way to view mounted drives in thunar?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't thunar automount drives? Basically "mount" command lists the mounted drives. [Here](http://thunar.xfce.org/documentation/C/using-removable-media.html) is some information regarding removable media and thunar. You can look into troubleshooting section for using thunar-volman.